# turn db json into javascript object using JSON.parse() failed

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6

I have `data json` that stored in mysql.

I do `console.log(data)`

I saw

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "sales": 10,
  "msg": "\"Have a nice day\"",
}
```

But I know it isn't a javascript object, because `console.log(typeof data) //string`

How can I turn it into javascript object? I do

`JSON.parse(data)` but I got error of

`Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`

Comment: There is a lot going on between: _I have data json that stored in mysql._ and _I do console.log(data)_. Please share that code.

Comment: This is puzzling as I see nothing wrong with your JSON. You have an extraneous comma after the message, but that shouldn't matter. What is really strange is your string doesn't even contain an `o` let alone at position 1. Are you positive data is what you think it is?

Comment: Umm, there are some questionable answers below...

Comment: @Brad... I knew it was not to spec, but for some reason I though parse was more forgiving. The Java json library i use doesn't mind such sloppiness, figured this wouldn't either. But just tested in js and, to my surprise, you are correct sir. thx, correcting...

Comment: bla, already edited a stupid typo up there. oh well...

Answer (score 1):

You got trailing comma, copy and paste your string to any json validator on the web.

the correct json format should be

```
{
 "id": "1",
 "sales": 10,
 "msg": "\"Have a nice day\"" -> delete the comma here
}
```

Answer (score -2):

UPDATED TO FIX LINE BREAKS

The problem is that a JSON object needs the brackets `{ }` but they are out of the string. Try to include the quotation sign outside everything (just be careful with the quotation sign for your strings). Something like this will work:

```
const myJsonString = `{
    "id": "1",
    "sales": 10,
    "msg": "Have a nice day"
}`

JSON.parse(myJsonString)
```

Comment: Clearly the brackets are there.  Also, your code won't parse... you would need to escape the newlines with a backslash.  Test what you post before you post it.

Comment: The brackets are there, but not inside the quotation sign, which is very different. you are right about the escape to the newlines, was trying to make it more readable and forgot that. I did test, but everything was inline. Thanks :)